# Django app structure, good practice?

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and am currently struggling with how to structure the apps.

The site is one with a public frontend, in which you can login to enter a dashboard. I've created a separate app for this dashboard.

Now I want to display a list of employees on one page of this dashboard, however I've created another app for these employees.

Should I create this new page/view, in the employees app? Or should I delete this employee app, and include that model in the dashboard app?
What is considered good practice?

It currently looks like this:

```
-site
-- dashboard app
-- employee app
```

Comment: I think your logic is correct. If the page is a part of the dashboard set of functionality, then that is where it should reside.

Comment: So you would advice to put it in dashboard? And then keep the models concerning employees in a separate employee app?

Comment: Yes. Employee/user related stuff could be in a separate app, which is consumed by the dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Source: [Two Scoops of Django: Best Practices for Django 1.8](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-8) p-35

Comment: So reading this would suggest that displaying the employees in the dashboard using the employees app?