# Can we make many views.py in Django as a Controller?

Tags: python, django

Iam new to Django Framework and just started learning django 1.8. In other framework Like `Laravel`,`Rails` there we can  make  different `controller file`. for example `UserController.php`,`ContactController.php` etc.

I think in Django, `views.py` is similar to `Controller`  and In django ,in `views.py` i have a long line of code of more than `300` lines and i want to make my code clean by making seperate `views.py` for `userRegistration`,`Contact`,`ArticleControl` etc. My question is how can i achieve this `ie:making many views.py like controller`

Comment: consider those as 'app' within your project and create apps for userRegisteration, Contact, ArticleControl.

Comment: You can definitely split the `views.py` up into multiple smaller files, just reference those files when importing them in your application.
Furthermore, the `views.py` isn't necessarily the controller, I would argue that `urls.py` is the controller.

Comment: it means i can make userRegistratio.py,Contact.py in views.py directory?

Comment: thanks you very much

Comment: @RanjeetKarki guide to app design in django: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31579099/1406040

Answer (score 4):

Instead of multiple views.py, You can divide your application into individual applications within your project. Like separate applications for `userRegistration, Contact, ArticleControl`. this way your code will look much cleaner. And in case of any bug you will be able to debug that specific application easily.

Comment: it means i can make userRegistratio.py in views.py directory?

Comment: Its a wrong way to create multiple file withs views inside. You code will become complicated. That's why multiple small application so that you can classify which file has views inside them. Also can you post a sample?

Comment: Also as @limelights said in comment on question, the controller part is `urls.py` file and if you create smaller apps as compared to multiple `urls.py` there is chance you will mess up the url routing part.

Comment: If you think the answer has solved your queries please upvote it as it will guide viewers who have similar problem. Also it will provide you and the answerer some reputation so no harm.

Comment: Creating a seperate application just to have seperate views sounds really bad.. i just cant understand why there's not a way to have multiple view functions in a class file

Comment: @sudhir it is a matter of personel preference. You can do that either way. All that matters is if your code is understandable to others (If you are working in a team.) Also It a more preferable to break your project into smaller application. Also read this post.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/28294439/4349666

Comment: I just figured out how to have some thing like controller with its own views.
i create a package named views, and inside that i create a book.py file with all the views related to book and this way i have some thing similar to a book controller with its views